# How to disable neo4j-import quotation checking

Tags: csv, import, neo4j

I try to import some large csv dataset into neo4j using the neo4j-import tool. Quotation is not used anywhere, and therefore i get errors when parsing using `--quote "` `--quote '` `--quote ´` and alike. even choosing very rare unicode chars doesnt help with this multi-gig csv because it also contains arabic letters, math symbols and everything you can imagine.

So: Is there a way to disable the quotation checking completely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it would be useful to have the import tool able to accept character configuration values specifying ASCII codes. If so then you could specify `--quote \0` and no character would match. That would also be useful for specifying other special characters in general I'd guess.

Comment: so actually, it is not yet possible to disable the delimiter search, right?

Comment: No I'm afraid it isn't

Comment: ok. I'm not in the mood to cherry-pick you change onto neo 2.3.1 and build it myself. So, the question is, how long will it take until that patch makes it into 2.3.2.

Comment: 2.3.2 and even 2.3.3 have been released now FYI.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the CSV file uses quotation marks, since they allow the tool to reliably determine when strings end.

Any string in your data file might contain the delimiter character (a comma, by default). Even if there were a way to turn off quotation checking, the tool would treat every delimiter character as the end of a field. Therefore, any string field that happened to contain the delimiter character would be terminated prematurely, causing errors.